# How to switch between touchscreen and mouse (or enable both)?

Tags: touchscreen, mouse

I have a [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/bone) with Android 4.1.2 and USB Keyboard and USB Mouse connected. With the [DVI-D](http://circuitco.com/support/index.php?title=BeagleBone_DVI-D) cape, keyboard and mouse work. But with the [LCD7 cape](http://circuitco.com/support/index.php?title=BeagleBone_LCD7), only the keyboard works. I assume that the touchscreen driver takes over and disables the mouse driver.

How can I switch between touchscreen input and mouse input, or enable them both?

(The reason that I want to use the mouse with the LCD is that the resistive touchscreen of the LCD7 cape is not enough responsive to use some Android applications. With the touchscreen it's e.g. nearly impossible to scroll within the Android settings dialog).